# How to input one word and read each letter and print via loop C

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I would like to input 5 words one word at a time and then with that word print out each letter of the word. However, I enter a while loop and it looks like the while loop never terminates after I enter the first word.

```
const int amountOfInputs = 5;    
 
for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfInputs; ++i)
{
    printf("Word Number # %d :\n", i );
    
    char reader;
    while(reader = getchar(), reader >= 0 ) 
    {
        printf("letters of word %d are: %c \n", i, reader);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting to terminate the loop? `reader >= 0` will not terminate until you type EOF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the while loop the following way

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

int reader;
while( ( reader = getchar() ) != EOF && reader != '\n' && !isblank( ( unsigned char )reader ) ) 
//...
```

That is separators of words are the space character `' '`, the tab character `'\t'` or the new line character `'\n'`. If you want to include spaces in words then the condition of the loop will look simpler

```
int reader;
while( ( reader = getchar() ) != EOF && reader != '\n' )
```